# Win7Pro 64bit Sleeps, then wakes up and finally hibernates

Tags: windows-7, suspend

I use Sleep/Suspend all the time since I rarely shut my laptop down. I probably Sleep/Suspend 5 or 6 times every day.  (Wake up, work at home, suspend, get on the bus, wake up, work, suspend, get to the office, wake it up, end of day suspend, get on the bus, wake it up, work, suspend... And so on).

Lately though I get up in the morning after Sleeping my laptop and find it has gone to hibernate, and the battery is dead.  Other days I find my laptop awake (Power light is no longer flashing sleep, but rather is on solid) and the battery down to 10-20%.  (With an SSD, my laptop actually can last all night turned on, it would seem...).

This morning I actually caught one stage of it.  I saw the power light on, and I double checked last night that it was Slept/Suspended properly before I went to bed.  But when I cam down, I saw the red battery about to die light, and disk activity, and then heard it shut down.

I.e. The core issue is that after being suspended the laptop is waking up on its own, it would seem.  Then running down the battery until it finally hibernates to protect the data.

So why would my Win7 Pro 64 bit machine start waking up inexplicably for no apparent reason, with no interaction from me?

My BIOS is NOT set to wake auto at any time.

My WLAN at home ought not to be sending any WOL packets.  (If I have someone breaking into my Wifi and sending WOL magic packets, I probably have way bigger problems...).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking in the Event Log, I see:

So att 11:16PM I suspended on my way to bed for the night.

At 3AM it work back up and then 8 seconds later Windows Update is in the log saying it is scheduled to install these updates at 3AM.

I know I had set my Windows Updates to download and ask me when to install.

But when I went and checked again, I found that it was now set to Automatically install important updates at 3AM.

This appears to have changed on me, which is annoying but lets see if this helps fix the issue.